# REGEX - Find text between strings - first optinal, but second only until first match

Tags: regex, between

I'm trying to extract text "THIS IS TEXT I WANT" from text below.
Thing is my regular expression doesn't stop at first occurrence of stop, but second.
First part, lookbehind is there, because first text doesn't have to be there.
What would be the correct expression to use?

Text:

> test1 THIS IS TEXT I WANT stop but here is another text stop and here is more

Regex:

```
(?<=test1).*stop
```

Current undesired output:

> THIS IS TEXT I WANT stop but here is another text stop

Desired output:

> THIS IS TEXT I WANT stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is just to write the regex like this

```
(?<=test1)(.*?stop)
```

The point is that you have to put a ? after the * so that it will make the previous operator lazy which means that it will stop at the first occurrence